# WPF привязка к нескольким условиям

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть форма с 3-мя полями `textbox` и кнопкой. Как сделать в xaml , чтобы до тех пор пока все 3 поля не заполнятся, то кнопка будет неактивна.
Для одного поля привязка понятна, а как для всех трех полей сделать ?

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=searchString, Path=Text.Length}
```

Comment: Не надо пытаться перенести логику на представление. Добавьте к модели свойство, которое будет возвращать нужный результат проверок.

Comment: стандартные пути: 1) свойство у вьюмодели 2) мультибиндинг/биндинг + конвертер 3) Это ж кнопка, а значит у команды есть CanExecute, который будет дисаблить кнопку пока условие не будет выполнено.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример реализации "мультибиндинг + конвертер" - один из вариантов, указанных @vitidev.

```
<!-- Где-нибудь в ресурсах -->
<local:IntToBoolMultiConverter x:Key="IntToBoolMultiConverter"/>

...

<Button Content="Test" Width="100">
    <Button.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IntToBoolMultiConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="SearchString1" Path="Text.Length"/>
            <Binding ElementName="SearchString2" Path="Text.Length"/>
            <Binding ElementName="SearchString3" Path="Text.Length"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

И сам конвертер:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int[]), typeof(bool))]
public class IntToBoolMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = values != null && values.All(x => x is int && (int)x != 0);

        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Хотя, задача конвертера (истина если нет нулей) не совсем очевидна по такому названию и лучше дать ему более конкретное имя.

Но в целом я согласен с @AlexKrass - здесь всё таки не какое-то изменение маргина или цвета, а включение/отключение функционала, и лучше это делать через вью-модель.

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить вариант без использования конвертера, но с триггерами.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="textBox1" />
    <TextBox Name="textBox2" />
    <Button Name="button" Content="button">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text.Length}" Value="0" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox2, Path=Text.Length}" Value="0" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```